# 2 Plots side by side in Rmarkdown based on one shiny widget

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown

I have a problem. I want to put two plots side by side in Rmarkdown Document:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
```

```{r,  echo = FALSE,fig.show='hold', out.width='50%'}
ggplot(mtcars,aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
ggplot(mtcars,aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
```
````

And it works fine. But additonally I'd like to add shiny widget which will related to both plots. In that way, plots don't show side by side.

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, fig.show='hold', out.width='50%'}
iteration <- sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))

selectInput('cyl', 'Choose number of cylinder:',
            choices = iteration,
            selected = iteration[1])
data <- reactive(subset(mtcars,cyl == input$cyl))

renderPlot(ggplot(data(),aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
  geom_point())

renderPlot(ggplot(data(),aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()) 
```
````

what should I change to get the desired effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you should personalize your layout as it indicated in [shiny tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html) for example dividing in 2 columns:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, fig.show='hold', out.width='50%'}
iteration <- sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))

selectInput('cyl', 'Choose number of cylinder:',
            choices = iteration,
            selected = iteration[1])
data <- reactive(subset(mtcars,cyl == input$cyl))

fluidRow(
  column(6, 
    renderPlot(ggplot(data(),aes(qsec, mpg)) + 
                 geom_point())
         ),
  column(6, 
    renderPlot(ggplot(data(),aes(disp, mpg)) + 
                 geom_point()) 
         )
)
```
````

In this case I've used a fluid grade system that you can change for a fixed (`fixedRow`)